# Apache passenger not start give error "undefined symbol: ap_rputs"

Tags: ruby, apache, ruby-on-rails-4, passenger

I have install apache2 passenger using below command initially apache2 was started but after installing rvm its give below error.

can some one help to find way i am getting this error and how to resolve this.

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 561F9B9CAC40B2F7
sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https

sudo vim /etc/apt/sources.list.d/passenger.list
deb https://oss-binaries.phusionpassenger.com/apt/passenger precise main
sudo chown root: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/passenger.list
sudo chmod 600 /etc/apt/sources.list.d/passenger.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-passenger



ubuntu@ip-23-31-39-60:~/www/fasterap/current$ sudo service apache2 reload
 * Reloading web server apache2
 *
 * The apache2 configtest failed. Not doing anything.
Output of config test was:
apache2: Syntax error on line 210 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax error on line 2 of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/passenger.load: Cannot load /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_passenger.so into server: /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_passenger.so: undefined symbol: ap_rputs
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the problem with sysupgrade from Debian wheezy to Debian Jessie.

The problem was solved in this scenario by installing the Passenger version that ends with ~jessie instead of ~wheezy, same for dependency packages that might break.

Because the versions contain codenames and are sorted in alphabetical order, aptitude thinks the wheezy version was the last one. It actually tells you it will "downgrade" the package to the jessie version.

Comment: I got the same problem but i did not find any passenger package with wheezy... I only have libapache2-mod-passenger with deb8 version.

Comment: It seems that /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/passenger-5.0.30/bin/passenger-install-apache2-module could help

Comment: I had to rename my vhost for Apache 2.4, change Allow/Deny apache2 configuration to match Apache 2.4 (require...). I also did create new sym link for Apache2 Redmine module => ln -s /path/to/redmine/extra/svn/Redmine.pm /usr/share/perl5/Apache2/Redmine.pm and change call to PerlLoadModule Apache2::Redmine

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem.
I reinstalled passenger and now it works.
First check if your repository address is correct:
deb https://oss-binaries.phusionpassenger.com/apt/passenger jessie main

```
a2dismod passenger
aptitude purge libapache2-mod-passenger  passengerpassenger-dev passenger-doc
apt-get update
apt-get install -y libapache2-mod-passenger
a2enmod passenger
service apache2 restart
```